# Why was Stack Exchange network closed before its relaunch in 2011?

Tags: support, bug

The Wikipedia says that Stack Exchange was:

> Launched on September 2009; 9 years ago. **(relaunched in
>   January 2011)**

Was Stack Exchange network really closed? If so, why?

Comment: I guess that was the year Stack Exchange 2.0 launched. You can try combing through the article's edit history to see when that text was added, then contact the editor who added it on their personal talk page (if they're still active).

Comment: I don't think a thing has to close in order to relaunch. It can just decide to make a pretty big change to itself and announce a "relaunch" as the changed thing.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange, and Stack Overflow has... well evolved over time.

Sadly the original post seems lost, but through the magic of the Internet archives, that's roughly the time that [Stack Exchange 2.0 was started](https://web.archive.org/web/20100416154936/http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0) and the current system of new site creation. It's around the time Stack Exchange in its *current* form was mooted.

Amusingly everything old is new again - as far as the post goes (we're still dealing with divergences in site code, you can buy a private SO instance...).

As someone who was *there* in the period SE was supposedly closed, I can assure you though it was never closed at all, or I was apparently wandering around the internet equivalent of a renovation site.

Comment: That blog post is still live at https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/13/changes-to-stack-exchange/; no need to go to WayBackMachine to get it.

Comment: The spelling changed from "StackExchange" (1.0) to "Stack Exchange" (2.0).